# Are there missable items?

Tags: tales-of-vesperia-de

I'm going for the Item Collector achievement and I've noticed that some items are pretty obscure - especially some of the costumes and attachments.

I'm wondering if there are missable items that you can't go back and get during the later parts of the game. I'm aware I can get them in new game+ but I'd rather get them during my first playthrough if possible.

Comment: My initial thought is *yes*, as Vesperia has a reputation of being one of the "harder" tales games to 100% due to quests/content/etc. locking over time & progress,  and sometimes only becoming available with some backtracking. I believe this extends to some items/collectibles as well. Let me see if I can put that into an answer with some research and content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are all varieties of items/collectibles that are missable and can be locked out. This ranges from weapons, to titles (and costumes), to even late game events/quests that may not become available due to missing a sidequest earlier in the game.

As I mentioned in my comment, Vesperia has the reputation of being more unforgiving than other Tales entries with regards to locking out content as the game progresses. It is recommended by folks experienced with the game's previous iteration that if you don't want to miss anything in a single playthrough, to use a walkthrough of the game, or at a minimum use one that points to these missable events, broken down by act. There is one such guide that many suggest which *attempts* to keep the spoilers to a minimum while pointing out these missable scenes/content/items.

https://ameblo.jp/koulinovesperia/entry-10347292825.html

If you've played through some of the first act, you can read some of the first lines of it to determine if the spoilers are too much for your taste to read it as you play through. Note: the items on the guide listed in blue text and labeled (ps3)  apply, as the definitive edition of the game comes with all the added content from the Japanese ps3 release.

Comment: After looking into your link, I've found a guide that is based off of the Japanese player's guide that you have. The link is this: https://www.scribd.com/document/397057683/Kouli-s-Guide-Tov